# Show that the edge set of a graph $H$ is a subset of $E(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n$ be a positive even integer. The graphs $G$ have vertex set $V (G) = \{v_1, v_2, . . . , v_n\}$
and edge sets $E(G) = \{v_iv_j| i,j=1,2,3,\dots, n, i\neq j\}$.
Also, the graph $H$ has a vertex set $V (H) = \{v_{\frac{n}{2}},  v_{(\frac{n}{2}-1)\text{mod n}}, v_{\frac{n}{2}+1}, v_{(\frac{n}{2}-2)\text{mod n}}, v_{\frac{n}{2}+2}, ..., v_{n}\}$ and edge set $E(H)=\{v_{\frac{n}{2}}  v_{(\frac{n}{2}-1)\text{mod n}}, v_{(\frac{n}{2}-1)\text{mod n}}v_{\frac{n}{2}+1}, v_{\frac{n}{2}+1}v_{(\frac{n}{2}-2)\text{mod n}},  ..., v_{n-1}v_{n}\}$.

How to show that the edge set of a graph $H$ is a subset of $E(G)$? And the graph $H$ is a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, that isn't true. There is an edge in $H$ including the vertex $v_{n \over 2}$ that isn't a vertex in the graph $G$ so the edge cant be in $E(G)$.

If $n$ is even, $V(H) \subset V(G)$ (assuming by $\mod n$ you mean take the value in $1,\dots, n$). $G$ is the complete graph so necessarily $E(H) \subset E(G)$.

**Here's the proof:**

Let $e = v_{\frac{n}{2}+k_1}v_{(\frac{n}{2}-k_2) \bmod n} \in E(H)$

Then, because $\frac{n}{2}+k_1 \in \{1,2,\dots , n\}$ and $(\frac{n}{2}-k_2) \bmod n \in \{1,2,\dots , n\}$, it follows that $e\in E(G)$.

**For distinctness of vertices of $H$**, let $v_{\frac{n}{2}+k_1} = v_{(\frac{n}{2}-k_2) \bmod n}$, then because $k_1$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{n}{2}-1$ and $k_2$ from $1$ to $\frac{n}{2}$, there can't be a "wrap-over". In another words $\frac{n}{2} > \frac{n}{2}-k_2 \geq 0$ and $\frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{n}{2}+k_1 < n $. Hence they are distinct.

Comment: Can you show it properly by showing the subsets?

Comment: @Kidie Is your mod to the range 1,...,n?

Comment: mod n where n is an even integer

Comment: I mean does $n \mod n = n$ or $0$? And for negatives too, will you get positives?

Comment: yes from $1,...,n$ you will get positives.

Comment: Ok, then it is true. I'll edit the proof in.

Comment: Also, can you show that the vertex of $H$ is distinct?

Comment: Okay, thank you. or should i post another question for showing the distinct vertices

Comment: Does $k_1\in 0,1,...,n-1$? because there is $\frac{n}{2}+0$

Comment: Yeah, I think so. it looks like $k_1 = 0,1,,\dots \frac{n}{2}$ and $k_2 = 1,\dots, \frac{n}{2}-1$.

Comment: oh i'm sorry $k_1$ is up to $\frac{n}{2}-1$ and $k_2$ is up to $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: btw what is the meaning of wrap over?

Comment: Oh, that was just informal talk about whether the mod gives back the actual value or do we actually have to add a multiple of $n$ to it to bring it to the range $1...n$. With these bounds, there actually is a one value of $k_2$ where that happens: for $k_2 = \frac{n}{2}$ we get $0$ and that turns to $n$ in the mod. But that's ok, since the other one is always less than $n$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Btw should I change $\frac{n}{2}>\frac{n}{2}-k_2\ge0$ into $\frac{n}{2}>\frac{n}{2}-k_2 \text{mod n }\ge0$

Comment: The value $\frac {n}{2}-k_2$ is what is inside the mod. When $k_2=\frac{n}{2}$ it is $0$ and the mod will give $n$.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand the first sentence when you let $v_{\frac{n}{2}+k_1}=v_{\frac{n}{2}-k_2}$

Comment: If the vertices are the same, then their indices must be the same, so $\frac{n}{2}+k_1 = (\frac{n}{2}-k_2) \bmod n$, so $k_1+k_2 \equiv 0 \mod n$ but then $k_1+k_2 = 0$, because it's positive and the biggest it can be is $n-1$ (when $k_1=\frac{n}{2}-1 and k_2=\frac{n}{2}$). So $k_1 = -k_2 < 0$ which is impossible. Hence this equality of the two different type of vertices is impossible. Same types  are clearly distinct (or the mod ones you can check similarly that they are distinct).